# How to run a function inside Vuforia's DefaultTrackableEventHandler.cs

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I'm trying to run a function inside `DefaultTrackableEventHandler.cs` after Vuforia detects the `target` by using the `protected virtual void OnTrackingFound()` but Vuforia can't detect the `namespace` that I'm using which is saved inside the `Assets` folder plus whenever I restart Visual Studio, every code that I've added to the `DefaultTrackableEventHandler` is deleted and the file is reset back to its original state. I think the problem might lie in the fact that `DefaultTrackableEventHandler.cs` is located inside the `Packages` folder while the script that I'm using for the `namespace` is inside the Assets folder.

How do I resolve this issue?